# can NHibernate use database index in a QueryOver?

Tags: nhibernate, second-level-cache

Suppose I have a entity with a id and a name fields. I want to look up those entities by name and I build a database index on the name field .

Now when I use NHibernate QueryOver, can NHibernate utilize the database index on name ?

if a second level cache is used , what algorithm will NHibernate use to find entites by name ?

Comment: What second level cache provider are you using?

Comment: I am using memcached for Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure about what algorithms memcached use, but they are reasonably fast. Note that you will have to configure your entity as using the second level cache in your NHibernate mappings.

Comment: thanks. I think I did . <cache usage="read-write"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate ultimately sends SQL to your database server. It is up to the SQL optimizer of your DB server (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc) to decide whether to use an index or not.